# Does Visual Studio Code have any extension for open and display table microsoft access ".mdb" file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I do not have MS Access on my machine. I want to open and display data table from MS Access Database file `.mdb`.

I'm not sure, does VS Code have any extensions for opening and display data table from MS Access Database file `.mdb`.

Thanks in advance.